# mysql - how to make columns to hold non duplicate values only

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me to make a mysql table to prevent duplicate entries in 3 columns only?.

I have 5 columns as below
id
username
email
serverip
dbport

I want to prevent duplicates only for id, email and serverip
Also I want to make the id auto increment.
Is it possible only with mysql?

Comment: Create/Set unique index on all that columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UNIQUE index for those fields, for example:

```
     ALTER TABLE `your_schema`.`your_table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `Index_Name`
     (`your_column`);
```

Add same index for each column you want to be unique.

For setting column to autoincerment:

```
     ALTER TABLE `your_schema`.`your_table` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` INT(10) 
     UNSIGNED NOT NULL, MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
     AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

(Make sure that you use your datatypes)

Comment: can u please tell me what should i put in `your_schema` ?

Comment: The name of your database.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks :), after i made those columns unique, i cannot insert blank rows to the columns. I must insert something or else im getting the error duplicate entry!!!! and the query doesn't end successfully.. is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @user3436585 you can modify column type to be NULLABLE, this will work

Comment: @Uriil still getting the error Duplicate entry '' for key 'serverip'